# Can we add validations for forgot password functionality in keycloak if we use invalid username or email to reset password

Tags: keycloak

As keycloak doesn't provide built in function for validations of forgot password while using the wrong email or username. So how can we add validations for this issue ?

I tried but using API by didn't know how to implement and connect that API with keycloak

Comment: So to start forgot password flow you have to send an email. So if user is found email will be sent, if not, nothing will happened. 
Beside that, find step in flow which you want to override and just create the same with your own logic, put it in the flow instead current and it should work as you like.